# Instantiate GameObjects over network

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I have a piece of code that is supposed to generate a random tile map which it does for the server only. I can't figure out how to get it to sync to the players when they join it.How would I sync the prefabs that are instigated to the joining players? They load on one player (the server) but when another player joins they don't show up.

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
public class GenerateLevel : NetworkBehaviour {
public int MapSize = 20;
public GameObject prefab;
public GameObject _LeftW;
public GameObject _RightW;
public GameObject _TopW;
public GameObject _Botw;
public GameObject SpawnLocRed;
public GameObject SpawnLocBlue;

public string map;
public override void OnStartServer()
{
    //base.OnStartServer();
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;

}

void Start()
{
    if (!isServer)
    {
        return;
    }


    for (int c = MapSize / 2; c > -MapSize / 2; c--)
    {

        for (int r = -MapSize / 2; r < MapSize / 2; r++)
        {
            var t = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(r, 0, c), 
Quaternion.identity);
            NetworkServer.Spawn(t);
            Debug.Log("Col:" + c + " Row:" + r);

            if (Random.Range(0, 3) == 2)
            {
                t.GetComponent<RAISE>().Run();
                map += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                map += 0;
                if (c < 0 - MapSize / 4 && r > 0 + MapSize / 4)
                {
                   var red= Instantiate(SpawnLocRed, new Vector3(r, 2, c), 
Quaternion.identity);
                }
                if (c > 0 + MapSize / 4 && r < 0 - MapSize / 4)
                {
                   var blue= Instantiate(SpawnLocBlue, new Vector3(r, 2, c), 
Quaternion.identity);

                }
            }

            map += "r";

        }
        map += "c";
    }
    Debug.Log(map);
    if (MapSize % 2 == 0)
    {
        GameObject wt = Instantiate(_TopW, new Vector3(-.5f, 0, -MapSize / 2), Quaternion.identity);
        wt.transform.localScale = new Vector3(MapSize, 5, 1);
        GameObject wb = Instantiate(_Botw, new Vector3(-.5f, 0, MapSize / 2+1), Quaternion.identity);
        wb.transform.localScale = new Vector3(MapSize, 5, 1);
        GameObject wl = Instantiate(_LeftW, new Vector3(-MapSize / 2-1, 0, .5f), Quaternion.identity);
        wl.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 5, MapSize+2);


        GameObject wr = Instantiate(_RightW, new Vector3(MapSize / 2, 0, .5f), Quaternion.identity);
        wr.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 5, MapSize+2);
    }
    else
    {
        GameObject wt = Instantiate(_TopW, new Vector3(-.5f, 0, -MapSize / 2), Quaternion.identity);
        wt.transform.localScale = new Vector3(MapSize-1, 5, 1);
        GameObject wb = Instantiate(_Botw, new Vector3(-.5f, 0, MapSize / 2 + 1), Quaternion.identity);
        wb.transform.localScale = new Vector3(MapSize-1, 5, 1);


        GameObject wl = Instantiate(_LeftW, new Vector3(-MapSize / 2 - 1, 0, .5f), Quaternion.identity);
        wl.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 5, MapSize + 1);


        GameObject wr = Instantiate(_RightW, new Vector3(MapSize / 2, 0, .5f), Quaternion.identity);
        wr.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 5, MapSize + 1);
    }
    Debug.Log(MapSize % 2);
}
```

Here is the updated snippet code

```
public GameObject[] tiles = new GameObject[1000];
public string map;
public override void OnStartServer()
{
    //base.OnStartServer();
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;

}
public void OnPlayerConnected(NetworkPlayer player)
{
    foreach(GameObject go in tiles)
    {
        NetworkServer.Spawn(go);
    }
}

void Start()
{
    if (!isServer)
    {
        return;
    }
    int temp = 0;

    for (int c = MapSize / 2; c > -MapSize / 2; c--)
    {

        for (int r = -MapSize / 2; r < MapSize / 2; r++)
        {
            var t = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(r, 0, c), Quaternion.identity);
            tiles[temp] = t;
            NetworkServer.Spawn(t);
         }
     }
}
```

After some fiddiling I got the tiles to spawn but they are not syncing ot the characters the henerate tile is running for each client seperatrly.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can't just use the `Instantiate` function to make prefabs show on the network. There are other things you must do:

**1**.You must register the prefab through the NetworkManager component. If there are more than one prefab, you must do this for all of them:

[image]

**2**.Attach `NetworkIdentity` component to the prefab. Note that if you also want to sync the objects transform, you must attach `NetworkTransform`  to the prefab too.

**3**.After instantiating the prefab, use `NetworkServer.Spawn` to also instantiate it on the network too.

For example:

```
//Instantiate on this device
GameObject red = Instantiate(SpawnLocRed, new Vector3(r, 2, c), 
Quaternion.identity);
//Instantiate it on all clients
NetworkServer.Spawn(red);
```

Finally, you may want to wrap all the code around inside `isLocalPlayer` to make sure you only instantiate from the local player.

```
if (isLocalPlayer)
{
    //Instantiate on this device
    GameObject red = Instantiate(SpawnLocRed, new Vector3(r, 2, c), 
    Quaternion.identity);
    //Instantiate it on all clients
    NetworkServer.Spawn(red);    
}
```

Comment: I have it all setup until step 3 but the problem is that the generator is random. How could I get it to run once and then sync it to all the clients? I added some pictures.

Comment: The-same thing I mentioned my answer especially **step 3**. Instantiate with `Instantiate` once and store the object in a List. When a new client joins, Loop over those Lists and instantiate them on the client with `NetworkServer.Spawn`.

Comment: No. Use List not array so that you can resize it. If it is server, instantiate with `Instantiate` and add to the List. No `NetworkServer.Spawn`......If it is client, loop over the List and instantiate with each one with  `NetworkServer.Spawn(currentListLoop);`

Comment: So something like"  public List<GameObject> tiles = new List<GameObject>();
    public void OnPlayerConnected(NetworkPlayer player)
    {
        foreach(GameObject go in tiles)
        {
            Instantiate(go);
            NetworkServer.Spawn(go);
        }
    } with  var t = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(r, 0, c), Quaternion.identity);
                tiles.Add(t); in the server only script

Comment: I added another image to display the desync that it is showing it looks like the maps are generating twice each not syncing with the last.

Comment: This really sucks, I am not on the computer to do a test. When get to my testing PC and I will see If I can replicate this issue.

Comment: would it help if I linked the full project for you

Comment: Sure. I use Unity 2017.2. Anything version with the-same or below is fine. Don't bother with any project made with Unity above this version since there will likely be unrelated problems.

Comment: Ok. Will test when I get on my test PC